# javafx: How can I put slider tick labels above its sliding track in horizontal slider?

Tags: javafx-8

I am trying to customize the horizontal slider such that its major tick labels appear above sliding track (by default they appear below sliding track) and major tick label values appear in reverse order. Do I need to use CSS somehow to display the labels above sliding track?

So far I have reversed the labels ordering using setLabelFormatter:

```
final double sliderMax = slider.getMax();
slider.setLabelFormatter(new StringConverter<Double>() {
    @Override
    public String toString(Double d) {
        return String.valueOf((int)(sliderMax - d));
    }
    @Override
    public Double fromString(String str) {
        return (sliderMax - Double.parseDouble(str));
    }
});
```

Any pointers will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://gist.github.com/flasheater/4f782780ec7d03f9c6abd29d269c3b9f) is certainly possible with CSS.

This will only work for horizontal Slider though. Theoretically there is the pseude CSS class `horizontal` on the Slider which could be used to restict the CSS to horizontal Sliders, but I was unable to test this, maybe you can make it work.

Check out the [CSS-Refrence](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#slider) and inspect your application with [ScenicView](http://fxexperience.com/scenic-view/).

Comment: Thank you for the help Oliver... this is what exactly I was trying to achieve.